# ID of contacts are incrementing after update (android API Level 7 and higher)

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm writing an application that synchronize android contact info with server info. After server info changed I'm updating all raw contacts and everybody happy. But I found out that after updating contact with several raw contacts, contact ID's value incremented by one. If I update contact from device contact ID will still be the same.

Assume that you have a contact with next data:

```
contact_id : 42
raw_contact_ids : { 43, 44, 45 }
```

(1) After update you'll have:

```
contact_id : 43
raw_contact_ids : { 43, 44, 45 }
```

(2) But if you update the same contact uisng your device with user interface you'll got:

```
contact_id : 42
raw_contact_ids : { 43, 44, 45 }
```

I don't understand such behavior. I assume it may be because contact aggregation but I don't understand the why results in (2) are not the same as in (1). I'm using next code for updating phone number data in raw contacts:

```
String selectPhone = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
    Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=? AND " + Phone._ID + "=?";
String[] selectArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(rawContactId), String.valueOf(from.getType()), String.valueOf(id) }; 
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(selectPhone, selectArgs)
    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
    .build());
```

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong? I really need those contacts IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've learnt you are better using LOOKUP_KEY when storing or using contacts, using the contact ID doesn't stay static due to aggregation.

Comment: What is LOOKUP_KEY and for what should I use it? I read about it on http://developer.android.com but didn't understand much. I'll be thankful for your explanation.

Comment: lookup_key essentially works out as a more static version of the contact_id. So for example when wanting to work with a contact you use this instead of the contact ID because from what I can tell it seems to stay more consistent across new device installs. Here's an eg getting contacts with some details including the LOOKUP_KEY: contactsCursor=context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(messageFromNumber)), new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY}, null, null, null);